# how to change UIButton border color Black to white

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

[image]i need to add a white border color on uibutton through run time attribute but its shows black all the time. how can I change black border colour to white?
i try this

```
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
button.layer.borderWidth = 2
button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

but it still showing me black 
i also try imageView here but can't able to change border color

Comment: Have you tried `button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor()` yet?

Comment: A UIButton has no border so the question makes no sense.

Comment: yes i try that it shows me black. i try in run time attribute or programmatically both it was shows me black all the time. i can't cable to change color.

Comment: @ChaudharyAnkitDeshwal So ? Is it working now ?

Comment: i did it earlier  but i can't change the colour that is my problem.

Comment: finally it work for me . it was not working through run time attribute. i now do this programatically and it work fine. my mistake is some of attribute i set from run time attribute.

Comment: if i accept an answer it would be the correct solution. but my ques is how to do change border colour run time attribute

Comment: @ChaudharyAnkitDeshwal Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 6):

Use this code:

```
   button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

   button.layer.borderWidth  = 2.0
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: please check my ques i update that

Comment: yeah  i just see your updated comment. Check it in somewhere of your code or storyboard you set it black color. Same code working at my end.

Comment: it was work with black color only you try to change the color.

Answer (score 4):

> **SOLUTION:**

```
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

button.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
```

Comment: i tried that but it default show black.

Comment: @ChaudharyAnkitDeshwal I had forgotten a line. Try now :)

Comment: thanks for ans but i try this line of code programatically or through run time attribute.

Comment: @ChaudharyAnkitDeshwal Put it in your `viewDidLoad()`